# Jdeveloper: How to create a .json file or a .txt file

Tags: json, text, jdeveloper

This is my first time doing project using Jdeveloper 10g. I am creating a JSP file to read some JSON object but I realized that there is no JSON file option as well as text file. Will it be the same if I create a File under General category and rename it to title.json or title.txt?

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes creating a generic file with the right name should work.
That being said, JDeveloper 10 is a very old version - pick up the newer JDeveloper 12c and you'll have much better support for JavaScript and JSON.